# Resources to integration with external web service at desktop level

Tags: arcgis-platform, hyperlink, integration, enterprise

I am using ESRI based GIS software, I looking a way to integrate ESRI solutions with external web service of other information system. For start I would like to join feature class to external tables and change there symbology dynamically by the on line data. later i would like to develop custom applications for the collection, conversion, maintenance, and analysis of data. Mainly visualization of external data in maps when data is streamed online.

**1.** is it possible to connect JSON web service to ArcGIS desktop without ArcGIS Server ? I'm using version 10.1 sp 1 Advance level

**2**. Where can i find resources to integrate GIS to external web service at desktop level ? I have no idea on where to start and to proceed further.

**3**. What ArcMap Tools and Commands host the trigger for calling the services ?

Comment: To try and help focus your question, I recommend reviewing http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/enterprise-gis/ and conducting searches on CRM and ERP here.  As it stands I think it is too broad for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: @Geog: I'll suggest that you expand your question by providing information on what exactly you want to achieve, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: 0down vote
 

What do you have on your server, what do you propose for the client guest? Are you an intranet serving an extranet, a url serving the web? what are your parameters and services. Do you own commercial licenses for packages and as a hosting solution or desktop? and what are they? Are you developing on a localhost and pushing to a VPS or spooling it up on Amazon AWS? Are you using ARC servers or are you using postgresql? Is it a spatial development environment or a service only? Depending on what service you call it's trivial, all the rest is the harder bit.

Comment: As stated in the question I didn't start yet and want to know whether it is possible, and if so would love to get reading sources to start learning the issue, mainly technical how to. RDBMS server has not yet been installed, thnaks

Comment: For starters I would like to join feature class to to external tables and change there symbology dynamically by the on line data

Comment: What's the source of the JSON data? Where is it coming from?

Comment: its coming form database as web service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, you should narrow down your question scope. However I decided to give an answer:

1. is it possible to connect JSON web service to ArcGIS desktop without ArcGIS Server ? I'm using version 10.1 sp 1 Advance level.

   - off course it is. I don't know what do you mean by a json web service! If you mean the response type (xml,json) of the web service, I can say most webservices requests and response can be both xml and json. With Arcmap you can consume all Esri (Map service,Feature Service,....) and standard spatial webservices (WMTS,WMS,WFS,WFS-T,WPS,WMTS) without programming. By the power of .Net programming (C#,VB) you can consume other w3c webservices such as custom soap and rest webservices. you should just write addins for ArcGIS Desktop.
2. Where can i find resources to integrate GIS to external web service at desktop level ? I have no idea on where to start and to proceed further.

   - [Consuming a Json Web Service from a C# or VB Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233698/Consuming-a-Json-WebService-from-a-Csharp-or-VB-Ap)
   - [Building custom UI elements using add-ins](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/)
3. What ArcMap Tools and Commands host the trigger for calling the services ?

   - using addins you can consume a web service when a button is clicked or you can consume web services spontaneously without user interaction and in the background (recommended). In the latter case I highly recommend you reading the multi-threading topic of ArcObject.[Writing multithreaded ArcObjects code](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/2c2d2655-a208-4902-bf4d-b37a1de120de.htm)